# Creating a request as XML in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, xmlhttprequest

I need to create a request with XMLDocument which have some specific values and i can't make it. My xml should look like that;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-9" ?> 
<ePaymentMsg VersionInfo="2.0" TT="Request" RM="Direct" CT="Money">
  <Operation ActionType="Sale">
    <OpData>
      <MerchantInfo MerchantId="006100" MerchantPassword="123" />
      <ActionInfo>
        <TrnxCommon TrnxID="">
          <AmountInfo Amount="1.00" Currency="949" />
        </TrnxCommon>
        <PaymentTypeInfo>
          <InstallmentInfo NumberOfInstallments="0"/>
        </PaymentTypeInfo>
      </ActionInfo>
      <PANInfo PAN="402275******5574" ExpiryDate="201406" CVV2="***" BrandID="MASTER" />
      <OrgTrnxInfo /> 
      <CardHolderIP>127.0.0.1</CardHolderIP>
    </OpData>
  </Operation> 
</ePaymentMsg>
```

Can anyone help me how to create this xml with using C# XmlDocument, XmlNode

I tried this,

```
 XmlNode node = null;
            XmlDocument _msgTemplate = new XmlDocument();
            _msgTemplate.LoadXml("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?><ePaymentMsg VersionInfo=\"2.0\" TT=\"Request\" RM=\"Direct\" CT=\"Money\">" +
                "<Operation ActionType=\"Sale\"><OpData><MerchantInfo MerchantId=\"\" MerchantPassword=\"\" />" +
                "<ActionInfo><TrnxCommon TrnxID=\"\" Protocol=\"156\"><AmountInfo Amount=\"0\" Currency=\"792\" /></TrnxCommon><PaymentTypeInfo>" +
                "<InstallmentInfo NumberOfInstallments=\"0\" /></PaymentTypeInfo></ActionInfo><PANInfo PAN=\"\" ExpiryDate=\"\" CVV2=\"\" BrandID=\"\" />" +
                "<OrderInfo><OrderLine>0</OrderLine></OrderInfo><OrgTrnxInfo /><CustomData></CustomData><CardHolderIp></CardHolderIp></OpData></Operation></ePaymentMsg>");
            node = _msgTemplate.SelectSingleNode("//ePaymentMsg/Operation/OpData/MerchantInfo");
            node.Attributes["MerchantId"].Value = "006100";
            node.Attributes["MerchantPassword"].Value = "123";
            node = _msgTemplate.SelectSingleNode("//ePaymentMsg/Operation/OpData/ActionInfo/TrnxCommon");
            node.Attributes["TrnxID"].Value = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            node = _msgTemplate.SelectSingleNode("//ePaymentMsg/Operation/OpData/ActionInfo/TrnxCommon/AmountInfo");
            string gonderilecekAmount = amount.ToString("####.00");
            gonderilecekAmount = gonderilecekAmount.Replace(",", ".");
            node.Attributes["Amount"].Value = gonderilecekAmount;
            node.Attributes["Currency"].Value = "949";
            node = _msgTemplate.SelectSingleNode("//ePaymentMsg/Operation/OpData/ActionInfo/PaymentTypeInfo/InstallmentInfo");
            node.Attributes["NumberOfInstallments"].Value = "0";
            node = _msgTemplate.SelectSingleNode("//ePaymentMsg/Operation/OpData/PANInfo");
            node.Attributes["PAN"].Value = "402275******5574";
            node.Attributes["ExpiryDate"].Value = "201406";
            node.Attributes["CVV2"].Value = "***";
            node.Attributes["BrandID"].Value = "VISA";
            node = _msgTemplate.SelectSingleNode("//ePaymentMsg/Operation/OpData/CardHolderIp");
            node.Attributes["CardHolderIp"].Value = "10.20.30.40";
            request = _msgTemplate.OuterXml;
            return request;
```

I think something wrong on CardHolderIp node. Any help would be useful.

Comment: And the code you have tried is where?

Comment: Sory, i added code which i tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the

```
 node.Attributes["CardHolderIp"].Value = "10.20.30.40";
```

line, i changed it to

```
 node.InnerText= "10.20.30.40";
```